# Codeigniter SQL table update with Ajax param not working

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

I hope someone can give me a hand because I've tried and tried to find the error with no luck, I'm trying to execute an update SQL statement which gets the values from a POST AJAX request and everything seems to work ok but the table's values doesn't get updated.

The App flow is like this (and it actually works, just without the data update):

In my view I have a button which detonates a modal window for the user to input values in 4 text fields, then the user can click on a button and it sends such values through a POST AjAX call, then the controller and the method takes care of the update, then the user is sent back to the same page where he/she originally clicked the button.

As additional information, paths are correct, the flow works correctly, the values are being sent correctly through the AJAX call to the controller but I'm lost from that point on...  :S

Not sure what I'm doing wrong, any help is appreciated

// My View - HTML button //

```
<a href="javascript:" onclick="service_report_additional_data(<?php echo $jobDetails[0]['job_id'] ?>)" class="dark_grey"><i class="fa fa-file fa-2x" aria-hidden="true" ></i></a>
```

// My View - HTML modal window code //

```
<div id="confirmation_box_service_report_additional_data" title="" style="display:none;">
    <h1 align="center" style="color: #333333"><?php echo $this->lang->line('service_report_title') ?></h1><br />
    <h2 align="center" style="color: #DF9E0A"><strong><?php echo $this->lang->line('project_service_comments') ?></strong></h2><br />
    <form id="form_service_report_additional_data" name="form_service_report_additional_data" method="post" action="">
        <table width="100%">
          <tr>
            <td width="45%" class="red_cell_background">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="client_images_comments"><?php echo $this->lang->line('client_images_comments') ?></label>
                  <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="client_images_comments"></textarea>
                </div>            
            </td>
            <td width="5%" class="purple_cell_background">&nbsp;</td>
            <td width="45%" class="purple_cell_background"><div class="form-group">
              <label for="specialist_images_comments"><?php echo $this->lang->line('specialist_images_comments') ?></label>
              <textarea name="specialist_images_comments" rows="5" class="form-control" id="specialist_images_comments"></textarea>
            </div></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="red_cell_background"><div class="form-group">
              <label for="spare_parts_comments"><?php echo $this->lang->line('spare_parts_comments') ?></label>
              <textarea name="spare_parts_comments" rows="5" class="form-control" id="spare_parts_comments"></textarea>
            </div></td>
            <td class="purple_cell_background">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="purple_cell_background"><div class="form-group">
              <label for="final_comments"><?php echo $this->lang->line('final_comments') ?></label>
              <textarea name="final_comments" rows="5" class="form-control" id="final_comments"></textarea>
            </div></td>
          </tr>
        </table>    
    </form>
</div>
```

// My Javascript modal window code //

```
function service_report_additional_data(jobId) {
    $("#spare_parts_comments").val("<?php echo $jobDetails[0]['spare_parts_description']; ?>");

    $("#confirmation_box_service_report_additional_data").dialog({
        autoOpen: false, 
        resizable: false,
        width: 900,
        heightStyle: "content",
        modal: true,
        closeOnEscape: false,
        open: function(event, ui) {
            $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close", ui.dialog | ui).hide();
        },      

         buttons: [
                {
                    text: "<?php echo $this->lang->line('save_and_close'); ?>",
                    class: "btn btn-warning",
                    click: function() {

                        var clientImagesComments = $('#client_images_comments').val();
                        var technicianImagesComments = $('#specialist_images_comments').val();
                        var sparePartsDescription = $('#spare_parts_comments').val();
                        var finalThoughts = $('#final_comments').val();

                                    //alert(finalThoughts)
                        servicereportadditionaldatasaving(jobId, clientImagesComments, technicianImagesComments, sparePartsDescription, finalThoughts);

                    },
                },
                {
                    text: "<?php echo $this->lang->line('Cancel'); ?>",
                    class: "btn btn-default",
                    click: function() {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            ],
            close: function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }     

        });

            $("#confirmation_box_service_report_additional_data").dialog('open');       
}
```

//My AjAX call //

```
function servicereportadditionaldatasaving(jobId, clientImagesComments, technicianImagesComments, sparePartsDescription, finalThoughts) {
                //alert(clientImagesComments)
   $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo base_url() . DISPATCHERADMIN . '/jobs/servicereportadditionaldatasaving/' ?>",
            data: {
                'jobId':                    jobId,
                'clientImagesComments':     clientImagesComments,
                'technicianImagesComments': technicianImagesComments,
                'sparePartsDescription':    sparePartsDescription,
                'finalThoughts':            finalThoughts
            },
            success: function (data){
                //alert(data);
                location.href = '<?php echo base_url() . DISPATCHERADMIN . '/myjob/details/' ?>' + jobId;
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                console.log('error:: ' + errorThrown);
            }
        });
}
```

// My Controller //

```
<?php

if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Jobs extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        // Construct the parent class
        parent::__construct();
        $this->lang->load('message', 'english'); // language file
        $this->load->model('dispatcher/jobs_model');
    }

    public function servicereportadditionaldatasaving() {       

        $postData = $this->input->post();
        $data = array(
                'table_name'                    => 'jobs',
                'job_id'                        =>  $postData['jobId'],
                'client_images_comments'        =>  $postData['clientImagesComments'],
                'technician_images_comments'    =>  $postData['technicianImagesComments'],
                'spare_parts_description'       =>  $postData['sparePartsDescription'],                                     
                'final_thoughts'                =>  $postData['finalThoughts']                                                      
        );
        $this->jobs_model->update_job_service_report_additional_data($data);
    }

}
?>
```

// My Model //

```
<?php

if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Jobs_model extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function update_job_service_report_additional_data($data) {      

        extract($data);
        $this->db->where("job_id", $job_id);
        $success = $this->db->update($table_name, array('client_images_comments'        => $client_images_comments,
                                                        'technician_images_comments'    => $technician_images_comments,
                                                        'spare_parts_description'       => $spare_parts_description,
                                                        'final_thoughts'                => $final_thoughts
                                            ));
        if($success) {
            return $success;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: have you tried to `var_dump($data)` in model?

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying, I've tried that but I don't seem to find the place to see the output of that, I mean, I've tried in the Browser debugger, Console and Network tabs and I can't see where it is being shown,

What I can see from the Network tab in the browser's developer tools is that the following params are being sent:
jobId=462
clientImagesComments=ccc
technicianImagesComments=eee
sparePartsDescription=aaaaa
finalThoughts=ffff

to the controller at:  http://localhost/mysite/dispatcher/jobs/servicereportadditionaldatasaving/

Comment: If you are using chrome developer tool go to network tab and select xhr filter then find your ajax url. You will see informations about request and response. If nothing shows in response, something goes wrong.

Comment: In my experience,  response is empty because an php error was emitted and config for displaying error was not enabled. I dont know whats your exact problem but hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, actually I've done that, the response is not empty and that is also something very odd, the response is the full HTML code of the page we are sending the user to...     O.o

Comment: I think you should see ajax response of `/jobs/servicereportadditionaldatasaving/` . Maybe you cannot find this url in network log because url redirecting will reset network logs. if you are in this case, check 'preserve logs' to prevent network logs to be cleared.

Comment: i think this is all i can help. good luck buddy

Comment: Hi and thanks for trying to help, I've also taken in consideration all your comments, by the way, I could totally find the  ajax response for the URL you are saying and the response is the Full HTML code, I have the preserver logs enabled and yet the result remains the same hehe, not sure what's going on, this shouldn't be that hard. Thanks though

Comment: your ajax call is not supposed to return html code because controller echo nothing. its very weird... sorry for asking again but did you really check ajax response for /jobs/servicereportadditionaldatasaving/?? I think it will be easier  if you use postman (chrome extension) to test your controller. This is my reeeal last comment. Good luck again!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself, after many attempts of looking into the code here and there I found that the problem was at the Ajax call at the following line:

```
url: "<?php echo base_url() . DISPATCHERADMIN . '/jobs/servicereportadditionaldatasaving/' ?>",
```

it was expecting an ID to be passed as part of the original URL as follows:

```
url: "<?php echo base_url() . DISPATCHERADMIN . '/jobs/servicereportadditionaldatasaving/' ?>" + jobId,
```

To be honest I need to review my code more in detail but that was the issue, everything is working as expected.